# Get a server certificate despite handshake failure in Python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am writing a tool to monitor server certificate expiration.  I'm using python3 ssl and socket modules to get the server cert using a pretty basic method of creating a default context, disabling hostname validation and certificate verification, calling `SSLSocket.connect()`, then `SSLSocket.getpeercert()`, with the sole purpose of grabbing the server certificate, and that is all.

This is all within a private network and I am not concerned with validation.

I have some devices that require client certs signed by a private CA (which my tool doesn't have), so the handshake fails on `SSLSocket.connect()`, making `SSLSocket.getpeercert()` impossible.

I know that the server certificate is indeed being provided to my client (along with that pesky Certificate Request) during the handshake.  I can see it in a packet capture, as well as just using the `openssl s_client` command line.

Here is my code.

```
def get_cert(self, host, port):
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    with ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=host) as s:
        s.settimeout(10)
        s.connect((host, port))
        binary_cert = s.getpeercert(True)
        cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, binary_cert)
        pem_cert = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert).decode()
        return pem_cert
```

Is there any way to get a little lower into the handshake messages to get the server cert, even though the handshake ultimately fails?

My current solution is to just run `openssl s_client -connect host:port` using `subprocess.run()` in the event of a ssl.SSLError.

Answer (score 1):

You may catch exception that `do_handshake()` produced and then continue to process server certificate.

```
import OpenSSL
import socket

dst = ('10.10.10.10', 443)
sock = socket.create_connection(dst)
context = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
connection = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(context, sock)
connection.set_connect_state()
try:
  connection.do_handshake()
except:
  print(connection.get_peer_cert_chain())
```

Tested on python 2.7.17 and 3.8.5

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your help.  I tried it and it's not working for my use case, which is when the server includes a 'certificate request' handshake and there is no matching client certificate, and the client sends a handshake failure.

Comment: if you gracefully catch handshake failure it should be ok to process peer cert chain, of course I tested with the client certificate request. What error do you have?

Comment: The OP is using `ssl` python module, which raises `ValueError: handshake not done yet` if you ignore the handshake exception and try `ssock.getpeercert()` anyway.

Comment: I have tested this and it works even for a service requiring client certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's unfortunately no way to do it with python's `ssl` module in versions < 3.10. In those versions, the only way to get the peer certificate that I can see is through the low-level `_ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert()` method and that immediately throws exception if the handshake is not complete.

Since python 3.10, there's a new `_ssl.SSLSocket.get_unverified_chain()` method that does not do the handshake check, so perhaps something like this abomination could work?

```py
ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, do_handshake_on_connect=False)

try:
    ssock.do_handshake()
except ssl.SSLError as e:
    pass

certs = ssock._sslobj._sslobj.get_unverified_chain()
```

... but I have not tested it.

Comment: Be aware that this is undocumented and may change in future versions. For further details and examples, see https://sethmlarson.dev/experimental-python-3.10-apis-and-trust-stores